# Is Image.Clip or Path.Fill faster when applying transforms (translate/rotate) on an image cutout?

Tags: silverlight

I'm having the user drag and rotate a clipped image using RotateTransform and TranslateTransform.

I want to lessen any image "flicker"/"jitter" during redraw as much as possible.

To create the clipped image, I can either use Image.Clip (to pathgeometry) or Path.Fill (with image).

Which would provide the smoothest experience for the user?

Comment: "There is only one way to find out, Fight!!" (UK entertainment media reference, please ignore if outside UK).   Seriously there is only one good way to find out, build stress examples of both techniques and compare.

Comment: Hi Anthony--agreed, and I did test both out. On my modestly beefed up dev computer both solutions were...ok. I saw both solutions do fine if dragged at slow-medium speed and both solutions caused the edges of the dragged images to break up slightly if dragged quite quickly. Test results: inconclusive so far.  So I'm just asking if anyone with more graphics experience has some advice to offer. BTW--you've got me curious: what does Fight!! mean? :)

Comment: "Fight!!" = http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Np6gyUb0E7o

Comment: Update: After more experimentation, I found that Path.Fill provides a little less "edge breakup" while the user is dragging image-filled-elements.  But!!  I found that using GPU acceleration greatly reduced "edge breakup". I set EnableGPUAcceleration to true and also set CacheMode=BitmapCache on the element being dragged.  I read that this turns the element into a bitmap that is cached in memory. Now "edge breakup" is hardly noticeable. Of course, this result is just on my computer--having modest built-in video.  I assume that some older computers won't be able to use GPU and will be slower.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: I watched Fight!! LOL!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Path.Fill (becose it's a simple texturing, for Image.Clip there is happening some additional computations)

Comment: Thanks Ai_boy, what you say does sound right.  I'm guessing it's faster to start with a known shape (path) and then just apply a texture to it.  It would be interesting to know what actually goes on "under the hood" of path.fill versus image.clip.

Comment: look at the 'moonlight' source code... it's not the same as Siverligth, but they have a lot of same 'things'....

Comment: Update: I ran across this confirmation that Path.Fill is faster than Image.Clip:http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=100043
For individual shapes, it is faster to express clipping or opacity as a different geometry or a different brush color. For example, draw a Path with an ImageBrush to achieve the same result as applying a clip to an Image element. Similarly, you can add opacity to the brush color alpha channel instead of adding Opacity to the shape.